# React Native TouchableOpacity running very slow in FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a `FlatList` that renders a list of music genres from Spotify API. Each item is a `Text` wrapped inside a `TouchableOpacity`. I have a `setState` that contains the genres I've selected and I have a `hasSelected` function that identifies if I have selected that genre or not.

This is my `FlatList` component:

```js
  <FlatList
   w="full"
   data={genres}
   numColumns={3}
   ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View className="p-1"></View>}
   renderItem={({ item }) => (
     <TouchableOpacity
       onPress={() => setMySelect((prev) => [...prev, item])}
       className="px-2"
     >
       <Text
         className={`rounded-full border font-kanit text-center  py-0 px-3 ${
           hasSelected(item, mySelect)
             ? "bg-tertiary text-gray-100 border-transparent"
             : "text-danube-400 border-danube"
         } `}
       >
         {item}
       </Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   )}
 />
```

If the item is selected it gets a background color. If the item is not selected, it just gets an outline. It's working fine, but **it's taking around 2 seconds to fill when selected**.
How can I improve its performance?

**Edit**

My `hasSelected` function is in another `utils.tsx` file and it's just this

```
export const hasSelected = (item: string, mySelect: string[]) => {
  return mySelect.includes(item);
};
```

Comment: Will you please share where you are initializing your `hasSelected` funtion?

Answer (score 2):

hope this will help you

here is [live](https://snack.expo.dev/@gattu/flatlist-exmaple) code

```
const renderitem=()=>{
      return(
              <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => setMySelect((prev) => [...prev, item])}
                  className="px-2"
              >
                  <Text
                    className={`rounded-full border font-kanit text-center  py-0 px-3 ${
                    hasSelected(item, mySelect)
                    ? "bg-tertiary text-gray-100 border-transparent"
                    : "text-danube-400 border-danube"
                    } `}
                  >
                  {item}
                  </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            )
}

  const App=()=>{
      return(
          <FlatList
           w="full"
           data={genres}
           numColumns={3}
           ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View className="p-1"></View>}
           renderItem={renderitem}
         />
    )
  }
```